# CSS Bootstrap 4 issue w inline fields

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to setup my form ( not being a CSS hero...) and I get the following input not so far from what I'd like :

[image: User registration Form]

But all input fields in the same group are same size (1/2 for name group fields and 1/3 for each address group fields )

How I can set

```
FirstName 1/3 . LastName 2/3 . ( even with only 2 fields ) 

Address 3/6 .  zipCode  1/6 . City 2/6 . ( even with 3 fields )
```

what's the trick ?... thanks for feedback

Comment: You haven't posted your current code but you know that you need to do that, right?

Comment: For someone with 2.5k rep, I expected a way better quality question.... Where is your current code? Make it a snippet so its easier for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap grid system. To apply 1/3 and 2/3 you have to add the css class `col-4` to the first name input and `col-8` to the last name input.

Bootstraps grid system is based in 12 cols. For further information please check the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width

Same with adress `col-6` zip-code `col-2` city `col-4`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved ..  using classes:   form-control col-n